# Como eu posso adicionar um caractere em cada elemento de uma string com Python?

Tags: python, lista

Temos a seguinte lista:

```
list=["oi","meu","nome","é","Gustavo"]
```

Desejo adicionar um caractere no início de cada elemento da lista (adicionei o nome `opa` em cada elemento manualmente mesmo :p):

```
list=["opaoi","opameu","opanome","opaé","opaGustavo"]
```

Como posso fazer isso com o Python?

Comment: Você utilizar python 2 ou 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Você pode fazer um simples for

Assim você percorre cada índice concatenando o "opa"

```
lista=["oi","meu","nome","é","Gustavo"]

nova_lista = []
for item in lista:
    nova_lista.append("opa" + item)

#Mostra o resultado da nova lista
for item in nova_lista:
    print(item + "\n")
```

## Ou usar o a função map

Utilizando uma expressão lambda `x: "opa" + x` e retornando uma lista a sua nova lista

```
lista=["oi","meu","nome","é","Gustavo"]

nova_lista = list(map(lambda x: "opa" + x, lista))

for item in nova_lista:
    print(item + "\n")
```

## Usar o map mas retornando para a lista original

Ao invés de retorna para uma nova lista, você pode continuar usando a lista original com os valores alterados

```
lista=["oi","meu","nome","é","Gustavo"]

lista = list(map(lambda x: "opa" + x, lista))

for item in lista:
    print(item + "\n")
```

## E com a ajuda do nosso amigo [Mário Feroldi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/39641/m%C3%A1rio-feroldi), há outra solução utilizando compreensão lambda de lista

```
lista=["oi","meu","nome","é","Gustavo"]

lista = [f"opa{x}" for x in lista]

for item in lista:
    print(item + "\n")
```

## O resultado de qualquer um dos métodos é o mesmo:

> opameu
>
> opanome
>
> opaé
>
> opaGustavo

Comment: Também existe compreensão de lista: `[f"opa{x}" for x in lista]`.

Comment: Obrigado @MárioFeroldi, editei a pergunta colocando mais esta solução :)

Answer (score 4):

A maneira mais direta e simples é utilizar [compreensão de lista](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
result = ["opa" + item for item in list]
```

A expressão `[f(x) for x in l]`, onde `f` é uma função qualquer que recebe um argumento e retorna algum valor, e `l` é uma lista qualquer, uma nova lista é criada aplicando a função `f` para cada elemento da lista `l`. Nesse caso, `f(x)` seria a concatenação das strings `"opa"` e de cada elemento `x`.